# Match in between dates

Tags: r

I have the following dataframes

```
#Clear Environment
rm(list=ls()) 

#Data to be matched
Data <- data.frame(
  Register = c(141 ,565, 1411,501),
  Name = c("Steve","Rbin", "Hero", "Cloud"),
  Date = c("43103", "43709", "43948", "43988"))

Map = data.frame(
  Register = c(141,141,141,565,565,565,1411,1411,1411,500,500,500),
  Name = c("Steve","Steve","Steve","Robin","Robin","Robin","Hero","Hero","Hero","Cloud","Cloud","Cloud"),
  Class = c("3A", "2F",   "1D",   "1A",   "2A",   "3C",   "1B","2A",  "3A","1A","2A","3A"),
  Gender = c("M","M","M","F","F","F","M","M","M","M","M","M"),
  StartDate = c("43526","43102","42986","42140","43081","43451","43345","43346","43903","42768", "43257","43954"),
  EndDate = c("43644","43513","43101","43060","43434","43415","42986","43485","43988","43159","43810","2958101"))


Data$Date = as.numeric(Data$Date); Map$StartDate = as.numeric(Map$StartDate); Map$EndDate = as.numeric(Map$EndDate)
Data$Date = as.Date(Data$Date, origin = "1899-12-30");Map$StartDate = as.Date(Map$StartDate, origin = "1899-12-30");Map$EndDate = as.Date(Map$EndDate, origin = "1899-12-30")
Data$Date = format(Data$Date, "%Y/%m/%d");Map$StartDate = format(Map$StartDate, "%Y/%m/%d");Map$EndDate = format(Map$EndDate, "%Y/%m/%d");
```

What I would like to do is find out the Class and Gender of the students using the mapping table based on their Register when their Date is in between the StartDate and EndDate

```
#Do a full left join and then subset rows when date is between startdate and enddate
s <- subset(merge(Data, Map, all.x = TRUE), Date >= StartDate & Date <= EndDate)
Joined = merge(Data, s, all.x = TRUE)  # add unmatched rows

  Register  Name       Date Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
1      141 Steve 2018/01/03    2F      M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
2      501 Cloud 2020/02/02  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
3      565  Rbin 2019/09/01  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4     1411  Hero 2020/04/27    3A      M 2020/03/13 2020/06/06
```

If their Register cannot be found on Map, take the Name.

```
i <- is.na(Joined$Class)
j <- c("Class","Gender")
Joined[i,j] <- Map[match(Joined$Name[i], Map$Name), j]

  Register  Name       Date Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
1      141 Steve 2018/01/03    2F       M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
2      501 Cloud 2020/02/02    1A       M        <NA>       <NA>
3      565  Rbin 2019/09/01   <NA>     <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
4     1411  Hero 2020/04/27    3A       M 2020/03/13  2020/06/06
```

In this set of script, it only allows me to Match the Class based on their Name, it does not take the Dates into consideration. So I would like Match to do the same thing as I did for Merge; Match and take the dates into considerations.

```
#Desired Output
  Register  Name       Date Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
1      141 Steve 2018/01/03    2F          M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
2      501 Cloud 2020/02/02    **3A**      M 2020/05/03 9999/01/01
3      565  Rbin 2019/09/01    <NA>       <NA>   <NA>       <NA>
4     1411  Hero 2020/04/27    3A          M 2020/03/13  2020/06/06
```

If possible, I would also want the script to be written as cleanly as possible for easier reading

1. Steve's Class is correct because the the Register and Date fits the criteria
2. Cloud's Class should be 3A instead of 1A due to the date
3. Rbin's Class should be NA because the Register and Name does not match Map *Rbin intentionally spelled wrongly
4. Hero's Class is correct because the the Register and Date fits the criteria

I would like to convert to d/m/Y format for Date, StartDate and EndDate? They're in Y/m/d for now

Comment: Why should Cloud's class be 3A? Cloud's 9999 EndDate makes no sense. Did you want to return the row with the latest date if register and date don't fit the criteria? Is Rbin purposefully spelled this way?

Comment: @latlio Hi I am very sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question yet again. Hope it clarifies. The 9999 year just means up to present date

Comment: Also Cloud has a Register = 501 in Data, but a Register = 500 in Map, is this intentional?

Comment: @latlio Yes it is.

Comment: @latlio this is a dataset that is meant to be replicating another working dataset that is being stored offline. The script for this should be very similar to what I want to use for my actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment! I think you code is doing what you want it to do but there are errors in your data as you can't get your desired output. For Hero the start date for the last entry is after the end date so it is filtered out, for Cloud and Rbin the there are no periods that include the date in the register. So only Steve has an entry. For example,

```
for(i in 1:4){
  print(Map[Map$Name==Data$Name[i]&Map$StartDate<=Data$Date[i]&
     Map$EndDate>=Data$Date[i],])
 }

  Register  Name Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
2      141 Steve    2F      M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
[1] Register  Name      Class     Gender    StartDate EndDate  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
[1] Register  Name      Class     Gender    StartDate EndDate  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
[1] Register  Name      Class     Gender    StartDate EndDate  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Another solution for getting what you want is

```
output <- Map[(Map$StartDate<=Data[match(Map$Name,Data$Name),'Date'] & 
              Map$EndDate>=Data[match(Map$Name,Data$Name),'Date']),]
output2 <- Map[!Map$Name%in%output$Name & !duplicated(Map$Name),]
output2[,c('Class','Gender',"StartDate","EndDate")] <- NA
output <- rbind(output, output2); rm(output2)
output

   Register  Name Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
2       141 Steve    2F      M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
4       565 Robin  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
7      1411  Hero  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
10      500 Cloud  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your comment, I have updated the question and adjusted the StartDate and EndDate.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a data-cleaning problem with lots of steps. There may be a more "automatic" way to do this, but I think by breaking down the data cleaning step by step, you have more control over how to manage messy data.

**Source of Untidyness**

The first thing I did was to verify the discrepancies in the data.

- Rbin is misspelled in `Data`
- Cloud has a different `Register` number in `Data` compared to `Map`

**Step 1: Correct `Register` error**

Assuming that the `Register` number for `Cloud` is correctly `501` as in `Data`, we can do the following:

```
names_with_incorrect_registry <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  distinct(Register) %>%
  count() %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  pull(Name)

join_df <- full_join(Data, Map, by = c("Register", "Name")) %>%
  mutate(Register = case_when(Name == names_with_incorrect_registry ~ 
                                Data %>% 
                                filter(Name == names_with_incorrect_registry) %>% 
                                pull(Register),TRUE ~ Register))
```

**Step 2: Get correct entries**

This is the easy step.

```
correct_entries <- join_df %>% filter(Date >= StartDate & Date <= EndDate)

  Register  Name       Date Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
1      141 Steve 2018/01/03    2F      M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
2     1411  Hero 2020/04/27    3A      M 2020/03/13 2020/06/06
```

**Step 3: Get "incorrect" entries**

```
name_not_in_map <- setdiff(Data$Name, Map$Name)
name_no_date <- join_df %>% filter(is.na(Date)) %>% pull(Name) %>% unique()
incorrect_entries <- join_df %>% filter(Name == name_not_in_map | Name == name_no_date) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(desc(EndDate)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  Register Name  Date       Class Gender StartDate  EndDate   
     <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     
1      501 Cloud NA         3A    M      2020/05/03 9999/01/01
2      565 Rbin  2019/09/01 NA    NA     NA         NA        
3      565 Robin NA         3C    F      2018/12/17 2018/11/11
```

**Step 4: `bind_rows()`**

```
out <- bind_rows(correct_entries, incorrect_entries)

  Register  Name       Date Class Gender  StartDate    EndDate
1      141 Steve 2018/01/03    2F      M 2018/01/02 2019/02/17
2     1411  Hero 2020/04/27    3A      M 2020/03/13 2020/06/06
3      501 Cloud       <NA>    3A      M 2020/05/03 9999/01/01
4      565  Rbin 2019/09/01  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5      565 Robin       <NA>    3C      F 2018/12/17 2018/11/11
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. This will only look for the Register in this code. What I hope to do is this; If the Class is NA after the Matching the Register, Map using Name. When matching using the name, the date filter should also be activated